# Will users be able to open my program without downloading Python?

Tags: python, compilation, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I'm making a program in python, but once I'm finished with the program, will the users have to download the python environment in order to use my program, or will it work without the python environment once compiled? Also, will it automatically be cross-platform or will I have to download a conversion program to make it work for Linux, Mac OS and Windows? I'm new to the language so this is confusing me.

Comment: Linux and OS X comes with python pre-installed, but for win users might have to dl python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Many Linux systems come with Python installed already. However, there are some tools to help if it is not:

- [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) for Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X (does not work for Python 3)
- [bbfreeze](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bbfreeze/) for Windows and Linux
- [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) for Windows
- [Freeze](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze) for Linux
- [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html) for Mac OS X

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) for windows, linux and mac is likely to have it preinstalled.

Answer (score 1):

They would need a python interpreter to use your program unless you turn your python script into a windows executable. One way of doing that is by using [Py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what 3rd party libraries you include in your program.

For example I never managed to make a windows executable with the PyQt lib,
by using py2exe. But this was 2-3 years ago and things might have changed.

Also don't hardcode paths in your program and make use of functions like [os.path.join](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

Don't make assumptions about config files and stuff. Do check on runtime the platform
your program is running on and act accordingly.

In general, your biggest problem will be the Windows platform.